# How to make sure to add response from server to ember store

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember.js for UI side development of application. For every action we are showing a modal popup and we have forms in that pop ups and then on form submission we have some respective actions which have controllers. Its working fine upto here, if we are making a web service call it is taking the server response and updating respective model js file in store.
So new requirement came that in that form if we give some value in a particular text field then a server call should go and fetch some information. Now the problem is, this value is not updating in store. The html(template) is like any html form and mouseout has some action calling on a particular field. That action is

```
App.MainFormSubmitActionController = App.ModalController.extend({
needs : 'application',
actions : {
    actionToBeCalled : function() {
            this.store.find('xyzModel');            
            //the above line should normally find xyzModal in store if not found then hit server and then update the store too
        },
    mainFormSubmitAction : function() {
             //some task done here
             }
     }
```

});

the json object I am getting back from server is :

> {"payload":{"xyzModel":{"gmp":25.0,"type":"someType","id":1}},"status":"SUCCESS"}

and the js file is

```
App.XyzModel = DS.Model.extend({
    "type" : DS.attr(),
    "gmp" : DS.attr()
});
```

The server call is happening fine, my problem is why ember store is not getting updated when I am getting a response and model not found error is not there. I google a lot but no one seems to have faced the same problem. What cud have I possibly done wrong.

Comment: I am still not sure what the reason for this, but i tried one thing and that is i converted the the value of gmp in output into string in server. And after this my ember store got updated with the values. Does it makr any sense to anyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember doesn't expect the model data to be wrapped in anything, what you can do is either change the api behaviour or you can customise your Application or Model serializer like so to extract the model and make it the top level object:

```
App.XyzModelSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id) {
    delete payload.payload.status;

    payload = {xyzModel: payload.payload.xyzModel };
    return this._super(store, type, payload, id);
  }
});
```

there are other methods for when mutiple records are returned, see http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html